# Google Drive API Android account selector always returns RESULT_CANCELED for some accounts

Tags: android, google-api-client, google-drive-android-api

I am integrating Google Drive API into my Android app to store a JSON file in the App Storage folder.

To do this I've implemented the Google Drive API in a fragment inside my MainActivity.

When I execute this code, it hits the onConnectionFailed method with the SIGN_IN_REQUIRED code, as expected. I execute startResolutionForResult and the account picker appears.

```
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection failed: " + connectionResult.toString());
    if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        if(!mConnectionResolutionInProgress)
        {
            try {
                mConnectionResolutionInProgress = true;
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(getActivity(), REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                // Unable to resolve, message user appropriately
                showMessage("There was an issue connecting to Google Drive services.");                    
            }
        }
        else
        {                
            mConnectionResolutionInProgress = false;
            showMessage("Canceling export/import action");                
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        mConnectionResolutionInProgress = false;
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(connectionResult.getErrorCode(), getActivity(), 0).show();            
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION)
    {
        mConnectionResolutionInProgress = false;
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
        {
            if(!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() && !mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting())
            {
                ConnectToGoogleDrive();
            }
        }
    }
}

private void ConnectToGoogleDrive()
{
    if(mGoogleApiClient == null)
    {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                .addApi(Drive.API)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
    }

    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
```

The strange thing is with my personal account (and my work account) it works just fine. I click my account, then dialog disappears, and it's replaced with the permissions dialog. If I accept that then the operation continues perfectly. The onActivityResult returns resultCode RESULT_OK.

If I use anyone else's account, the account picker disappears and I hit one of my error cases. If I debug I see that the resultCode is actual RESULT_CANCELED.

I don't see what the difference is. It looks like my code is pretty standard.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using a google account (i.e. gmail or google apps domain)? If you are using google apps domain, can you verify if Drive is enabled for that user?

Comment: By verify you mean ensure they're already using Google Drive? That's true in both cases I've tested that have failed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could be an app signature issue - if you are testing successfully on debug, but failing on release, you may not have the correct keystore signatures set up in the Google API Console - if that is the case, you should be able to add the second signature to the console as well, and both debug and release builds will work fine.

Comment: It turned out my Oath2 debug credentials obviously don't work when built from a different PC. When I tried a release Oauth2 credentials, it worked fine.